# Update SQL column data by adding text in between data in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I have two columns

| ID | XML |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | <a id='1'></a> |
| 2 | <a id='2'></a> |

Now I want to search data that starts with <a> tag and update the xml entry, I want to add extra tag in between <a> tag for all the rows.

Note : This is sample data. I need all the child nodes present under <a> to come under <b> and the child nodes will vary for every row.

> Sample : <a id='1'><b></b></a>

How do I use the update statement to fetch that data and and add <b> tag in between xml and save it.

Comment: is that suitable to use `REPLACE('</a>','<b></b></a>')`  for your case ?

Comment: This is just a sample data, there are lot of tags in between<a> and it varies for every row and all that data will come inside <b> tag @barbaros-Özhan.

Comment: As I guessed seems you need more, then need to explain the cases more.

Comment: "all that data will come inside <b> tag" - do you mean you want child nodes currently directly under `a` to move inside the new `b` node, so adding a new level in the existing structure? Or that the new `b` node will be a sibling of the other nodes under `a`? If it's more complicated than you've shown you should edit your question to include representative examples.

Comment: @AlexPoole yes your right, I need all the child nodes of <a> to come under <b> and the child nodes will vary for every row.

Comment: Then please update your question to say that and include clear examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use XQuery update:

```
update your_table
set xml = xmlquery('
  copy $i := $p1
  modify (
    for $j in $i/a
    return insert node $p2 into $j
  )
  return $i'
  passing xml as "p1", xmltype('<b></b>') as "p2"
  returning content)
where xmlexists('$p/a' passing xml as "p")
```

or with such a simple new node (if it really is):

```
update your_table
set xml = xmlquery('
  copy $i := $p1
  modify (
    for $j in $i/a
    return insert node $p2 into $j
  )
  return $i'
  passing xml as "p1", xmlelement("b", null) as "p2"
  returning content)
where xmlexists('$p/a' passing xml as "p")
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=082d0215107564817462413e437b4050)

Read more about [updating XML data](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adxdb/query-and-update-XML.html#GUID-6AE99020-C3C8-44EB-8E54-40188E1103F2) in the documentation.

---

> I need all the child nodes present under <a> to come under <b>

You could still do this with an XQuery update; can't help thinking it could be done more simply, but this creates a copy of the `b` node, then copies all the other nodes under `a` into it, delete those nodes directly under `a`, an dinserts the new `b` - including the copied children - under `a` instead:

```
update your_table
set xml = xmlquery('
  copy $i := $p1
  modify (
    for $j in $i/a
    return insert node (
      copy $k := $p2
      modify (
        for $l in $j/*
        return (
          insert node $l into $k/b
        )
      )
      return $k
    )
    into $j,
    delete nodes $i/a/*
  )
  return $i'
  passing xml as "p1", xmltype('<b></b>') as "p2"
  returning content)
where xmlexists('$p/a' passing xml as "p");
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=fda45f547e970f0c533da041f7161a25) with some expanded sample data with and without child nodes.

---

You *could* also do this with `regexp_replace`, as an advance on Barbaros' suggestion in comments; at least with small XML documents:

```
update your_table t
set xml = xmltype(regexp_replace(t.xml.getstringval(), '(<a.*?>)(.*?)(</a>)',
  '\1<b>\2</b>\3', 1, 0, 'n'))
where xmlexists('$p/a' passing xml as "p");
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=faface0d8dc188d9fedd33bab4fc0ff9)

but for some reason it isn't working with `getclobval()` - not sure if that's a big in this specific version. However, unless the structure is very well known and controlled this is likely to do something odd at some point, so it's really just for interest. It's safer to manipulate XML *as* XML rather than as a string.

And then there's XLST... but someone else can make suggestions using that.